# Make in_array not convert between numeric and alpha values

Tags: php

I want to make in_array return TRUE in these cases:

```
in_array(0, [0]);
in_array(0, ['0']);
in_array('0', [0]);
in_array('0', ['0']);
```

But at the same time, return FALSE in cases such as this:

```
in_array(0, ['A']);
in_array('0', ['A']);
in_array('A', ['0']);
in_array('A', [0]);
in_array(1, [true]);
```

What's the simplest solution to this?

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to write your own version of `in_array()`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_intersect` works as expected except last case

```
php > var_dump((bool) array_intersect([0], [0]));
bool(true)
php > var_dump((bool) array_intersect([0], ['0']));
bool(true)
php > var_dump((bool) array_intersect(['0'], [0]));
bool(true)
php > var_dump((bool) array_intersect(['0'], ['0']));
bool(true)
php > var_dump((bool) array_intersect(['0'], ['A']));
bool(false)
php > var_dump((bool) array_intersect(['0'], ['A']));
bool(false)
php > var_dump((bool) array_intersect(['A'], ['0']));
bool(false)
php > var_dump((bool) array_intersect(['A'], [0]));
bool(false)
php > var_dump((bool) array_intersect([1], [true]));
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of your examples are working, except

```
in_array(0, ['A']);
```

However, you can convert your integer value to string like that:

```
in_array(strval(0), ['A']);
```

This will work even if there are numbers in an array:

```
in_array('0', [0]); // returns true
```

Or:

```
$needle = 'A';
$array = [0];
in_array(strval($needle), array_map(function($value) { return strval($value); }, $array));
```

Or:

```
$needle = 'A';
$array = [0];
$mapped_array = array_map(
    function($value) {
        if (is_numeric($value))
            return strval($value);
        else
            return $value;
    },
    $array
);
in_array(strval($needle), $mapped_array, true);
```

Comment: I also don't want to return true in reverse: `in_array('A', [0])`. I have edited the question. And now it's starting to be complicated, because I need to santize all the values in an array. You see where I'm going with this.

Comment: in_array(strval('A'), array_map(function($value) { return strval($value); }, [0]));

The idea that you convert to string not only needle, but elso all elements in your array

Comment: That will also return TRUE if needle is `1` and array is `[true]`, though. So now it starts to be even more complicated. I was hoping for simpler solution. I just don't want PHP to use numerical values of other values than numeric for comparison.

Comment: You need to understand, what do you want. If you has anything in needle and in array and you want to compare values types, you should use strict mode (3-rd parameter of in_array). If you want `in_array(0, ['0']);` to return true, that means there cannot be strict comparison. If you want that `in_array(0, ['0']);` will return true, but `in_array(1, [true]);` will return false, that means your requirements are not consistent and impossible in a common case.

Comment: I want to make strict comparison in numeric sense, not in data type sense. 0 and '0' are both numeric and I want to evaluate them as equal. `0, 'A', 1, and true` are not, so I don't want them to evaluate as equal

Comment: I edited my comment. Possibly, it is what is required for you. The idea to have the same type for numbers, but allow everything as is for other values. In the same manner there can be a type conversion to integer etc.